# Effect without corresponding reducer?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a form that needs to persist some data. I don't need to save the data in the store. Is it a good approach to write 
- an action to trigger
- an effect
- no reducer, no selector, no state properties?

It seems a valid approach to me but I never saw it anywhere before.

PS: I'm using the latest Angular version and the latest ngRx version

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a valid way to do it.
Imho, storing a form in the ngrx store and keeping it in sync is an overkill in most scenarios.

I'm not sure if it's been discussed in the following article, but I highly recommend to read it - https://blog.nrwl.io/ngrx-patterns-and-techniques-f46126e2b1e5 and https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b.